# Did I install React Native module Sample project correctly

Tags: reactjs, react-native, node-modules

I am a RN beginner and I would kindly appreciate, if I could get a bit of feedback, whether I correctly installed React Native project with a module and the example of it. I have not been able to find resources that explain this entire process correctly.

The module and example I am attempting to install is ReactNative: Native Photo Editor: https://github.com/prscX/react-native-photo-editor

I believe I have a correct prerequisites with Node.js, Java and Android Studio, all the latest official version. To my understanding, this module does not support Expo, which I however do have but I use npx with this.

My process:

```
npx react-native init test
cd test
yarn add react-native-photo-editor
Download project Zip, extract Example folder content to /test
Add code to built.gradle and app activities as instructed in [1]
npx react-native run-android
```

Is this the correct way of adding a module on RN or whether I am doing something wrong?

Comment: For this package, additional setup is required. For this package to work on android you'll have to make updates to build.gradle and manifest file. Please go through the 'Getting Started' section: https://github.com/prscX/react-native-photo-editor#rn61--rnpe-v1-

Comment: Hi @SagarShakya. Apologies, I forgot to add this to the process, I of course adhered fully to the instructions and made the updates. I will edit the description, sorry for forgetting this. With this part done, would the process be considered correct way to install RN module?

Comment: The installation process depends on the package. For some, just doing a `yarn add` or `npm install` will make the package run, but for some package, those which have to interact with native modules, for eg, this `react-native-photo-editor` package requires permission for camera and storage, so you'll have to make updates to the native android and ios files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two types of RN library: `JS Only` and `JS + Native Code (I called RN Module)`. When you install library with JS Only, just run `npm install --save library_name` or `yarn add library_name`. That's enough. If you install RN Module, after install library, you must link it to connect Javascript and Native code. The simple way to know RN library type: look at source code structure in github/node_modules, if you see android/ios folder, it might be a `RN Module`.

Since RN 0.60, React Native CLI was supported auto linking. If auto linking doesn't work, you must follow manual installation section in the module document.
If your project is using RN < 0.60, run `react-native link module_name` to link library.

Some module use native part like xml, android Activity,...and use some permission like CAMERA, STORAGE, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,...so if you install it, you must follow their document setup to can be use.
For example, you are using [react-native-photo-editor](https://github.com/prscX/react-native-photo-editor), it use an android Activity to display the editor, so you must add it to Androidmanifest.xml.

In short: add library from npm -> check is RN Module -> Setup base module document. Sorry for my bad English.